# How to display divs lined up under parent for tree link display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

progress:
https://jsfiddle.net/zigzag/wkf0ufat/6/

How do I make sure that respective teams `three teams in each vertical column` line up right under the parent div of NBA, NFL and NHL. I called quits on `css` gymnastics here where we need to think of horizontal layout for first and second row but vertical layout in the third row. Third row is a list of teams. I started with Grid layout but realised that using `IE 11` I couldn't try it.

```js
$('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).find('span').toggleClass('glyphicon-triangle-bottom').toggleClass('glyphicon-triangle-right');
  var clickValue = $(this).attr('id');
  //do switch statement based on clickValue. Right now it selects the id of first just fine.
  //first: toggle second and hide third
  //second: show
  $('#secondRow').toggle();
});
```

```css
.container-fluid {
  margin: 5px;
}

.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  background: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

#firstRow,
#secondRow {
  text-align: center;
}

#secondRow>div {
  display: inline-block;
}

span {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

span:hover {
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.thirdRow {
  text-align: left;
}

.thirdRow div {
  dispaly: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" id="firstRow">
    <div class="center-block box">
      <img class="img-circle" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=IMAGE" />
      <p>Leagues</p>
      <a class="menu-toggle" href="#" id="first">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" id="secondRow">
    <div class="box">
      <img class="img-circle" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=IMAGE" />
      <p>NBA</p>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img class="img-circle" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=IMAGE" />
      <p>NFL</p>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img class="img-circle" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=IMAGE" />
      <p>NHL</p>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row thirdRow" id="NBArow">
    <div class="box">
      <img class="img-circle" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=IMAGE" />
      <p>Warriors</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img class="img-circle" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=IMAGE" />
      <p>Rockets</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img class="img-circle" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=IMAGE" />
      <p>Celtics</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row thirdRow" id="NFLrow">
    <div class="box">
      <img class="img-circle" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=IMAGE" />
      <p>Penguins</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img class="img-circle" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=IMAGE" />
      <p>Kings</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img class="img-circle" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=IMAGE" />
      <p>Ducks</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row thirdRow" id="NHLrow">
    <div class="box">
      <img class="img-circle" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=IMAGE" />
      <p>Penguins</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img class="img-circle" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=IMAGE" />
      <p>Kings</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img class="img-circle" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=IMAGE" />
      <p>Ducks</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question mentions a tree view, which is really a collection of nested lists. The block view you describe requires making some levels of nested list layout horizontally and some levels vertically, but the content is really just a list of lists (or a list of a list of lists...)

Here's a snippet that uses lists for markup. One with default styles and one with some styles to achieve the columns you want. This method will accurately display more or fewer lists than the example.

```js
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).next('ul').slideToggle()
});
```

```css
.blocks {
  font-size: 0;
}

.blocks a,
.blocks span {
  display: block;
  background: #ddd;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.blocks ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.blocks li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.blocks ul ul ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>Tree</h3>
<div class="tree">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Leagues</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">NFL</a>
          <ul>
            <li><span>Bears</span></li>
            <li><span>Lions</span></li>
            <li><span>Browns</span></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">NBA</a>
          <ul>
            <li><span>Clippers</span></li>
            <li><span>Hornets</span></li>
            <li><span>Nets</span></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">NHL</a>
          <ul>
            <li><span>Sabres</span></li>
            <li><span>Blackhawks</span></li>
            <li><span>Bruins</span></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<h3>Blocks</h3>
<div class="blocks">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Leagues</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">NFL</a>
          <ul>
            <li><span>Bears</span></li>
            <li><span>Lions</span></li>
            <li><span>Browns</span></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">NBA</a>
          <ul>
            <li><span>Clippers</span></li>
            <li><span>Hornets</span></li>
            <li><span>Nets</span></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">NHL</a>
          <ul>
            <li><span>Sabres</span></li>
            <li><span>Blackhawks</span></li>
            <li><span>Bruins</span></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Jason. I like the simplicity of this. I do need to add more details for each team so it should almost expand like a box. I suppose throw a little box class on it and wrap a bunch of divs around each li should work to get there?

Comment: If you put a single div as the child element inside the team li elements you can keep the list organization and logic separate from the box display logic. You can add as many divs or other elements you want inside of that div to achieve the right look. If you get a start and need a hand making it work, let me know.

Comment: Hi Jason, slight change on direction on this (horizontal style instead of vertical org). So it will look like nested accordion. But based on your feedback I'm trying to style this with UL LI. Here is where I am. I have two markups to get there. one with nested divs and one with li. https://jsfiddle.net/zigzag/aLb5d2uL/8/ and https://jsfiddle.net/zigzag/nmdcef7L/. Thoughts on ideal markup?

Comment: Bootstrap just uses block elements like divs for their collapsible sections, so there's some backup to go with divs. If your content is really nested lists though, and the lists look right with out the styles, id stick with that route. I don't think that either way would save you a ton of code in the js.